# How to set up a plotting loop correctly?

Tags: r, for-loop

im still a rookie struggling with the set up of a plotting loop (*.png files).
"opening device failed". Honestly, I don't know how to handle that.

My approach:

```
names =list(Pic1,Pic2,Pic3,Pic4,Pic5,Pic6,Pic7,Pic8,Pic9,P10)


for (i in 1:10){

mypath <- file.path("C:","Users",paste("myplot_",names[i],".png"))
png(file=mypath)
mytitle = paste("Training PIC", names[i])
par(mfrow=c(3,1), oma=c(2,2,4,2))
boxplot(ERRORS.train.pic[[i]], outline=F, ylab="RMSE(-)", xlab="K-No")
abline(h = 0, col = "red")
plot(sapply(ERRORS.train.pic[[i]], median), ylab="MEDIAN-RMSE(-)", xlab="K-No",type="l", col="blue")
plot(sapply(ERRORS.train.pic[[i]], mean), ylab="MEAN-RMSE (-)", col ="red")
title(main= mytitle, outer=T)
dev.off()
}
```

I receive the following error code:

```
Error in png(file = mypath) : kann png()-Gerät nicht starten
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png(file = mypath) :
  kann Datei 'C:/Users/myplot_ A .png' nicht zum Schreiben öffnen
2: In png(file = mypath) : opening device failed
```

I'd highly appreciate some hints on that issue. Thanks in advance,
Olli

Answer (score 0):

apparently the file.path function was the problem. I went another way and fixed that.

my solution:

```
dir <- "C:\\Users\\"
    names =list(Pic1,Pic2,Pic3,Pic4,Pic5,Pic6,Pic7,Pic8,Pic9,P10)
    for (i in 1:10){

    mypath <- paste0(dir,"Training-Result",names[i],".png")
    png(file=mypath)
    mytitle = paste("Training PIC", names[i])
    par(mfrow=c(3,1), oma=c(2,2,4,2))
    boxplot(ERRORS.train.pic[[i]], outline=F, ylab="RMSE(-)", xlab="K-No")
    abline(h = 0, col = "red")
    plot(sapply(ERRORS.train.pic[[i]], median), ylab="MEDIAN-RMSE(-)", xlab="K-No",type="l", col="blue")
    plot(sapply(ERRORS.train.pic[[i]], mean), ylab="MEAN-RMSE (-)", col ="red")
    title(main= mytitle, outer=T)
    dev.off()
```

any way someone could present a way how to use file.path I'd still appreciate that. cheers!